# Python 2.x True & False returning True in very specific case

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

I've searched everywhere for an answer to this, sorry if it's a very basic question. I am filtering Numpy arrays using a boolean Numpy array that is created by comparing values at the same indices in 3 different arrays. My comparison is comprised of 2 separate boolean statements, say x[i]==y[i] & x[i]!=z[i], for all indices i. Here's the troubling results:

```
x[8]=25

y[8]=27

z[8]=13

x[8]==y[8]

False

x[8]!=z[8]

True

x[8]==y[8] & x[8]!=z[8]

True
```

As you can see, the above False & True returns a True. What am I missing? As another example of my frustration, here's another example from the same arrays that is returning the proper results:

```
x[3]=24

y[3]=18

z[3]=27

x[3]==y[3]

False

x[3]!=z[3]

True

x[3]==y[3] & x[3]!=z[3]

False
```

As you can see, this example works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing?

You're missing parentheses:

```
(x[8]==y[8]) & (x[8]!=z[8])
```

Also, you should be doing this as a vectorized operation over the whole arrays, rather than by looping over indices. Hopefully, you're doing that in your real code, and you just used specific indices here to make the example simpler:

```
(x == y) & (x != z)  # Evaluates to an array of booleans.
```

`&` is the bitwise AND operator, not the logical AND, but since logical `and` can't be overloaded for broadcasting (with good reason), NumPy uses `&` for logical AND on boolean arrays. `&` has different precedence from `and`, so you need to parenthesize some operations you wouldn't need to parenthesize with `and`.

Comment: "NumPy uses `&` for logical AND on boolean arrays" Which actually makes sense, as logical and bitwise operations on boolean are essentially the same (especially if you consider True as 1 and False as 0)

Comment: Thank you! This was a great answer and fixed everything immediately. And yes, I was just using specific indices as an example. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

do (x[8]==y[8]) & (x[8]!=z[8])
or even better
x[8]==y[8] and x[8]!=z[8]